# Get text value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my markup like this

```
<div class="text-input-area">
    <input type="text" id="text-input"/> <br />
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Preview" />
  </div><!--.text-input-area-->
```

In the input area I will type only text. Now when I will click on button Preview it should show the text that I had type. For that I have made my jquery like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#button').click(function() {
      var textvalue = $( "#text-input").text();
        alert('textvalue');
    });
  });
  </script>
```

But its not working at all. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gmeEL/

**API**:

- `.val()` : http://api.jquery.com/val/

Hope this will fit the cause `:)`

**code**

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#button').click(function() {
      var textvalue = $( "#text-input").val();
        alert(textvalue);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$( "#text-input").val()` instead of `$( "#text-input").text()` and `alert(textvalue)` instead of `alert('textvalue')`

Complete Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#button').click(function() {
      var textvalue = $( "#text-input").val();
        alert(textvalue);
    });
  });
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2UmHX/)

Answer (score 0):

Two problems

1. need to use .val() to get the value of an input field
2. need to use the variable `textvalue` for the alert not a string literal `'textvalue'`

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var textvalue = $("#text-input").val();
        alert(textvalue);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for inputs and select use `$(selector).val()`
for span use `$(selector).text()`

Answer (score 0):

It should be a `val()` i.e. a jquery function that returns a `value` of the element

```
var textvalue = $( "#text-input").val();
```

Please note that

> The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or
>   get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val()
>   method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method.

http://api.jquery.com/text/